# Sometime display Database connection Error, while loading 100 user in Jmeter. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos, jmeter, lamp

I have handle the media project in codeIgniter framework.

I have completed the project. but I should load testing in JMeter and mention 100 users.

Running the successfully almost 50 users, then often display Database not connection error.

Refer the Codeigniter Database Settings

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'sample',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache/db_cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Refer the screenshot for JMeter image

How to fix that issue ?

Thanks Advance !!!

[JMeter image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5USn.jpg)

Comment: we cant see your image. add code instead of image

Comment: @Abdulla Now are you see that image ?

Comment: Please add code here without image

Comment: @Abdulla What code you need ? I have added the codeIgniter database connection settings coding.

Comment: code  which is related to this question

Comment: Check max_connections for your MySQL server. Default value is 151 which might be not enough for your test. ```SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';```

Comment: already, I have set the max_connections is 5000. that is okay ?

Comment: @Abdulla Database connection problem, while access the more then 100 users in our site.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL default max connections is 100.

If you want to increase it see [article](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404374/how-do-i-increase-the-mysql-connections-for-my-server).